# Qgis composer attribute table

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2

I'am trying to make an atlas composer to get export for each line of a specific layer. Those lines are portions or roads.

In the print composer I have 2 maps, a picture frame and 3 attribute tables

I would like to only show in those attribute tables the specific line of the feature concerned by each page of the atlas. Actualy even with the "show only features intersecting atlas feature" option I got sometimes 3 lines in those tables.

Any idea on how to deal with this?

Comment: Maybe they are indeed intersecting atlas feature? Intersect != covers != crosses

Comment: Yes I think so, as they are shown in the canvas. Bus how could I get only one feature at a time?

Comment: Yes, you can. You can filter out to single atlas feature using filtering by expression... you've got few variables to get reference to atlas feature

Comment: Ok, then I tried this:
filter with expression "@atlas_feature )" 
But got 0 result. I also tried " @atlas_featureid " but alsway got the 1st feature as a result for every page of the atlas. Any tips?

Comment: expression... you need operator, like 4 eg. 'id = @atlasfeatureid'

Comment: or 'id = @atlasfeaturenumber' cause this first is counting from 0 since i have id's from 1

Comment: Worked out with "ID"  =  @atlas_pagename 
Thank you !

Comment: Ok, so I'll make some answer from it - just for posterity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting more than one line because other lines also in intersects this atlas feature.
To do this you have to use filtering by expression (button with epsilon). There is few variables to get actual atlas feature properties. You can use:
id_from_altasFeatureLayer = @atlas_feature or @atlasfeatureid

Comment: The one that worked for me was: "ID" = @atlas_pagename
Don't know why but as I said earlier in the topic, "atlas_feature" and "atlas_featureid" gave me bad result (no result at all or many lines)
Thank you for the answer I hope that will help some people